# visual studio - i cant open live server

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

i installed the live server on my visual studio but i cant open it. i already uninstalled the visual code and installed again, but the problem persist the message that shows when i try to open is this one

Open a folder or workspace...(file-> Open Folder)
Source Live server (extension).

When i click to stop it, it says that

Server is not already running

I dont know what to do

i already uninstalled the visual code and installed again, but the problem persist

Comment: on your question be exact if you use VS or VSC

Answer (score 0):

Try closing all files,

File/Open Folder
Select folder in which the file is
Select the file in the VS explorer
Right click in the file content
Open with File Server